# Can I pass values from data entry attributes into my Contact Update activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Using the Journey Builder I am creating/updating data extension records using journey entry data.

Some of the fields I need to update are Boolean and Date columns, it appears these types of fields in the target DE can only have static values and not dynamic variables like my text columns. (see image attached)

[image]

Is there any way around this? aside from turning my attributes into Strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, using dynamic values into the data extension via update contact activity is not yet possible.

It is still in Ideas - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TthMQAS. Please feel free to vote for it if you need it.

For now, you can only use static values, boolean to set True or False, set the date or use current date time in update contact activity.

As a workaround you can add an ampscript snippet on the top of email to [insert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertde.htm)/[update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatede.htm)/[upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm) the data extension with dynamic values.

Or you can try using [custom journey builder activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm) to be built to using the Marketing Cloud APIs to update rows in data extensions to each Contact evaluated by the activity.

Note -  Building a custom activity requires time and resource commitments, typically ongoing, to build and maintain the application used by the activity and the environment it operates within.